# Get list of Chocolatey packages using API

Tags: chocolatey

Is there a way to use the OData api on the chocolatey.org site to obtain a list of all packages available in the community repo?

What I've tried:

I can see using the $metadata service that Packages is exposed:

https://chocolatey.org/api/v2/$metadata

From this I can use something like this to get the first "page" of XML:

http://chocolatey.org/api/v2/Packages()?$skip=0

The website limits to 40 "entries" by default I think, so the $skip can be altered accordingly.

(Another way is to use the $skipToken which points to the next "page").

All versions seem to return in the responses. It would be irresponsible to write a loop to effectively download the database. I don't think the site owners would appreciate this. I'm not planning to do this regularly.

Reasons for doing this aside, is there a better way to get the package list using only the API, not via the choco CLI?

Update 1
Getting warmer using filters - clue in the metadata
eg. https://chocolatey.org/api/v2/Packages()?$filter=IsLatestVersion
This now returns latest versions only at least.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on why you need this information?

Comment: Good qn. The Chocolately WPF GUI is a little heavy/sluggish for my liking. Purely as an exercise in learning node/electron, I envisage some personal cached version launched from the windows tray. Even if there is something like this, it's a good learning exercise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use something like [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to inspect the traffic going from the Chocolatey CLI. Issuing `choco search git` reveals the following request:

```
GET /api/v2/Search()?$filter=IsLatestVersion&$skip=0&$top=30&searchTerm='git'&targetFramework=''&includePrerelease=false HTTP/1.1
```

Please note that you shouldn't be using their API without contacting them first. Even if it's just for personal use. They have no public documentation for their APIs, and so it should be treated as an internal resource.